# Diferença nos gráficos da Análise de Componentes Principais (PCA)

Tags: r, ggplot2, aprendizagem-de-máquina

Hoje eu estava analisando um conjunto de dados e percebi algo que nunca tinha reparado anteriormente. A fim de visualizar um conjunto de dados multivariado, criei a sua PCA e projetei as observações nas duas componentes principais. Para isto, utilizei os pacotes `ggplot2` e `ggfortify`. Vou reproduzir os resultados com outro conjunto de dados, que não é aquele que estou analisando, mas o mesmo fenômeno ocorre. Os resultados estão abaixo:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggfortify)

iris.pca <- prcomp(iris[, -5])
ggplot(iris.pca$x, aes(x = PC1, y = PC2)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
autoplot(iris.pca)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Percebam que, qualitativamente, eu tenho o mesmo resultado em ambos os gráficos. A diferença entre eles surge na escala: enquanto a Componente Principal 1 (PC1) do gráfico chamado `ggplot2` varia entre aproximadamente -3 e 4, esta mesma PC1 no gráfico chamado `ggfortify` varia entre aproximadamente -0,125 e 0,15. Comportamentos similares ocorrem nas outras componentes principais.

Eu sei que o `ggplot2` não está errado, pois ao calcular as estatísticas de `iris.pca$x`, eu obtenho valores que batem com o que o gráfico mostra:

```
summary(iris.pca$x)
      PC1               PC2                PC3                PC4            
 Min.   :-3.2238   Min.   :-1.37417   Min.   :-0.76017   Min.   :-0.5054344  
 1st Qu.:-2.5303   1st Qu.:-0.32492   1st Qu.:-0.17582   1st Qu.:-0.0778999  
 Median : 0.5546   Median : 0.02216   Median :-0.01639   Median : 0.0007274  
 Mean   : 0.0000   Mean   : 0.00000   Mean   : 0.00000   Mean   : 0.0000000  
 3rd Qu.: 1.5501   3rd Qu.: 0.32542   3rd Qu.: 0.20550   3rd Qu.: 0.0896801  
 Max.   : 3.7956   Max.   : 1.26597   Max.   : 0.69415   Max.   : 0.5053050
```

Portanto, o que está acontecendo com a função `autoplot`? Que transformação ela está aplicando em meus dados para deixá-los com esta amplitude reduzida? E por que ela faz isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A função `autoplot` do `ggfortify` faz um tipo de padronização. Mais especificamente faz o seguinte:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggfortify)

iris.pca <- prcomp(iris[, -5])

x <- apply(iris.pca$x, 2, function(x) x/(sd(x)*sqrt(nrow(iris))))

ggplot(x, aes(x = PC1, y = PC2)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-03-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Existem várias formas diferentes de padronizar os resultados dos componentes principais como mostram a [essa resposta](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/276746/44359) (em inglês) e outros links que ela cita. Cada uma com um motivo diferente.

Ao meu ver o autor do `autoplot` apenas escolheu uma padronização para o output da função para diversos pacotes do R que também fazem análise de componentes principais e usam diferentes metodologias para padronizar os resultados.